# Java webrowset.readXml() throws SQLException

Tags: java, xml, readxml, rowset

I have a `testWebRowset()` with a `webRowset` object that creates an xml, populates it and manipulates some of the data and then it tries to read the xml file. Definitely not adding or removing columns though... After that it creates another instance of `WebRowSet` that tries to read this xml. At this point  the mothod `readXml()` throws an SQLException saying "Invalid column index" and I just can't see what is the reason for this.

Can you help me to figure it out? Thanks.

The code:

```
public void testWebRowSet() throws SQLException, IOException {
    FileReader fReader;
    FileWriter fWriter;
    String priceListFileName = "pricelist.xml";
    int[] keyCols = {1};
    WebRowSet priceList = new WebRowSetImpl();

    priceList.setUsername("tom");
    priceList.setPassword("mypassword");
    priceList.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TestDatabase/");
    priceList.setCommand("select * from item");
    priceList.setKeyColumns(keyCols);

    // Populate the WebRowSet
    priceList.execute();
    System.out.println("Size of the WebRowSet is: " + priceList.size());

    // Insert a new row
    priceList.moveToInsertRow();
    priceList.updateString("ITEMID", "S1002");
    priceList.updateString("NAME", "Scanner");
    priceList.updateFloat("PRICE", 8.99f);
    priceList.insertRow();
    priceList.moveToCurrentRow();
    System.out.println("New row inserted");
    System.out.println("Size of the WebRowSet is: " + priceList.size());

    //Delete the row with "Scanner"
    priceList.beforeFirst();
    while(priceList.next()) {
        if(priceList.getString(2).equals("Scanner")) {
            System.out.println("Deleting row with Scanner...");
            priceList.deleteRow();
            break;
        }
    }

    // Update price of Printer
    priceList.beforeFirst();
    while(priceList.next()) {
        if(priceList.getString(2).equals("Printer")) {
            System.out.println("Updating row with Printer...");
            priceList.updateFloat(3, 6.99f);
            priceList.updateRow();
            break;
        }
    }

    int size1 = priceList.size();
    fWriter = new FileWriter(priceListFileName);
    priceList.writeXml(fWriter);
    fWriter.flush();
    fWriter.close();

    // Create the receiving WebRowSet object
    WebRowSet receiver = new WebRowSetImpl();
    receiver.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TestDatabase/");
    receiver.setUsername("tom");
    receiver.setPassword("mypassword");

    //Now read the XML file.
    fReader = new FileReader(priceListFileName);
    receiver.readXml(fReader);
    int size2 = receiver.size();
    if(size1 == size2) {
        System.out.println("WebRowSet serialized and "
                + "deserialiazed properly");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error....serializing/deserializng the WebRowSet");
    }
    priceList.acceptChanges();
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error inserting values : Invalid column index
    at com.sun.rowset.internal.XmlReaderContentHandler.endElement(XmlReaderContentHandler.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:858)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.rowset.internal.WebRowSetXmlReader.readXML(WebRowSetXmlReader.java:109)
    at com.sun.rowset.WebRowSetImpl.readXml(WebRowSetImpl.java:182)
    at DB.DB.testWebRowSet(DB.java:175)
    at DB.DBtest.main(DBtest.java:28)
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error inserting values : Invalid column index
    at com.sun.rowset.WebRowSetImpl.readXml(WebRowSetImpl.java:200)
    at DB.DB.testWebRowSet(DB.java:175)
    at DB.DBtest.main(DBtest.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<webRowSet xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdbc http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdbc/webrowset.xsd">
  <properties>
    <command>select * from item</command>
    <concurrency>1008</concurrency>
    <datasource><null/></datasource>
    <escape-processing>true</escape-processing>
    <fetch-direction>1000</fetch-direction>
    <fetch-size>0</fetch-size>
    <isolation-level>2</isolation-level>
    <key-columns>
      <column>1</column>
    </key-columns>
    <map>
    </map>
    <max-field-size>0</max-field-size>
    <max-rows>0</max-rows>
    <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
    <read-only>true</read-only>
    <rowset-type>ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE</rowset-type>
    <show-deleted>false</show-deleted>
    <table-name>item</table-name>
    <url>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TestDatabase/</url>
    <sync-provider>
      <sync-provider-name>com.sun.rowset.providers.RIOptimisticProvider</sync-provider-name>
      <sync-provider-vendor>Oracle Corporation</sync-provider-vendor>
      <sync-provider-version>1.0</sync-provider-version>
      <sync-provider-grade>2</sync-provider-grade>
      <data-source-lock>1</data-source-lock>
    </sync-provider>
  </properties>
  <metadata>
    <column-count>4</column-count>
    <column-definition>
      <column-index>1</column-index>
      <auto-increment>false</auto-increment>
      <case-sensitive>true</case-sensitive>
      <currency>false</currency>
      <nullable>1</nullable>
      <signed>false</signed>
      <searchable>true</searchable>
      <column-display-size>6</column-display-size>
      <column-label>ITEMID</column-label>
      <column-name>ITEMID</column-name>
      <schema-name>TOM</schema-name>
      <column-precision>6</column-precision>
      <column-scale>0</column-scale>
      <table-name>ITEM</table-name>
      <catalog-name></catalog-name>
      <column-type>12</column-type>
      <column-type-name>VARCHAR</column-type-name>
    </column-definition>
    <column-definition>
      <column-index>2</column-index>
      <auto-increment>false</auto-increment>
      <case-sensitive>true</case-sensitive>
      <currency>false</currency>
      <nullable>1</nullable>
      <signed>false</signed>
      <searchable>true</searchable>
      <column-display-size>15</column-display-size>
      <column-label>NAME</column-label>
      <column-name>NAME</column-name>
      <schema-name>TOM</schema-name>
      <column-precision>15</column-precision>
      <column-scale>0</column-scale>
      <table-name>ITEM</table-name>
      <catalog-name></catalog-name>
      <column-type>12</column-type>
      <column-type-name>VARCHAR</column-type-name>
    </column-definition>
    <column-definition>
      <column-index>3</column-index>
      <auto-increment>false</auto-increment>
      <case-sensitive>false</case-sensitive>
      <currency>false</currency>
      <nullable>1</nullable>
      <signed>true</signed>
      <searchable>true</searchable>
      <column-display-size>22</column-display-size>
      <column-label>PRICE</column-label>
      <column-name>PRICE</column-name>
      <schema-name>TOM</schema-name>
      <column-precision>15</column-precision>
      <column-scale>0</column-scale>
      <table-name>ITEM</table-name>
      <catalog-name></catalog-name>
      <column-type>8</column-type>
      <column-type-name>DOUBLE</column-type-name>
    </column-definition>
    <column-definition>
      <column-index>4</column-index>
      <auto-increment>false</auto-increment>
      <case-sensitive>false</case-sensitive>
      <currency>false</currency>
      <nullable>1</nullable>
      <signed>true</signed>
      <searchable>true</searchable>
      <column-display-size>22</column-display-size>
      <column-label>QUANTITY</column-label>
      <column-name>QUANTITY</column-name>
      <schema-name>TOM</schema-name>
      <column-precision>15</column-precision>
      <column-scale>0</column-scale>
      <table-name>ITEM</table-name>
      <catalog-name></catalog-name>
      <column-type>8</column-type>
      <column-type-name>DOUBLE</column-type-name>
    </column-definition>
  </metadata>
  <data>
    <modifyRow>
      <columnValue>S1002</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Scanner</columnValue>
      <columnValue>8.99</columnValue>
      <columnValue><null/></columnValue>
    </modifyRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>001</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 01</columnValue>
      <columnValue>2000.0</columnValue>
      <columnValue>20.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>002</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 02</columnValue>
      <columnValue>1000.0</columnValue>
      <columnValue>5.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>003</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 03</columnValue>
      <columnValue>20.2</columnValue>
      <columnValue>25.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>004</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 04</columnValue>
      <columnValue>1500.0</columnValue>
      <columnValue>40.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>005</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 05</columnValue>
      <columnValue>1600.0</columnValue>
      <columnValue>40.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>006</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 06</columnValue>
      <columnValue>1700.0</columnValue>
      <columnValue>45.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>007</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Item 07</columnValue>
      <columnValue>1800.0</columnValue>
      <columnValue>1200.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
    <currentRow>
      <columnValue>P1002</columnValue>
      <columnValue>Canon Printer</columnValue>
      <columnValue>60.2</columnValue>
      <columnValue>9.0</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
  </data>
</webRowSet>
```

Comment: Code and exception pls.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I should have posted this straight away.

Comment: Can you post the XML file generated by the `WebRowSet` instance?

Comment: I put a breakpoint just before `receiver.readXml(fReader)` executes so this is what it works with...

Comment: Just one idea (may be unrelated, but currently I'm not able to see anything wrong): why do you have duplicated rows in your XML? Shouldn't the first column be a unique key of the table? That's how you configure the rowset and it's also visible in the `properties` section of the XML.

Comment: edit: ah, I see now, indeed, the values in the first column should be unique indeed. I don't know why it allowed me to duplicate the data. However I re-created the table and run the app again and the problem's nt solved yet, it's the same exception...

Comment: Are you getting the same XML, only with your duplicates removed? Is there any row with more than 4 columns?

Comment: Can you use a debugger? I would attach the sources for `com.sun.rowset.internal.XmlReaderContentHandler` and try to see which is the XML element it processes when the exception at line 741 occurs.

Comment: No rows with more than 4 columns as far as I can see.

Comment: I have tried it in netbeans, is it the `Project properties/Sources`? I could do it but I don't know where to find `com.sun.rowset.internal.XmlReaderContentHandler` I tried in all my Java folders I must be blind. First time I'm trying to do debugging like this.

Comment: OK I figured out I can do this in Window/Debugging/Sources and realised that the `XmlReaderContentHandler` should be in src.zip however it is not there. Checked for its superclass `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` and I can find that (just to see if I am a the right place) but there is no `rowset` folder within `com.sun` and no `XmlReaderContentHandler` within the whole zip file. I am stuck here, any avice?